# VS2008 Setup Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dependencies, setup-project

I have a C# project, built using VS2008.  It has a number of third party dependencies.  However, when I create a set-up project for it, the “Detected Dependencies” folder is empty.  How do I either force it to detect these dependencies, or manually add them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the output from another project, or some other assembly (could be an executable), and then the setup project will automatically detect the dependencies and will add the corresponding assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

- Within the Solution Explorer right click on the setup project and select **Add - Project Output**.
- Now select your other project within the solution.
- The Detected Dependencies should be filled up.